# Why does IF statement checking for x86 program files directory result in an error message?

Tags: batch-file

I have XP and Win7 PC's. Inside my batch file I have to provide the path to executable. In order to differentiate OS's I wrote this batch file ... BUT it didn't work and gave me an error.

```
@echo off
if EXISTS %ProgramFiles(x86)% (
   set PATH="c:\Program Files (x86)\McAfee\VirusScan Enterprise\"
) else (
  set PATH="c:\Program Files\McAfee\VirusScan Enterprise\"
)
echo %PATH%
REM pushd %PATH%
```

The error was: `C:\Program was unexpected at this time.`

What's wrong with my batch?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you do NOT want to overwrite `PATH`. Quite a bit of important things depend on it; instead, you should be appending to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better use this batch code:

```
@echo off
if exist "%ProgramFiles(x86)%" (
    set "PATH=%PATH%;%ProgramFiles(x86)%\McAfee\VirusScan Enterprise"
) else (
    set "PATH=%PATH%;%ProgramFiles%\McAfee\VirusScan Enterprise"
)
echo %PATH%
REM pushd %PATH%
```

There are several mistakes in your batch code.

1. **exist** instead of *EXISTS*. There is no *s* at end of this keyword.
2. The missing double quotes as the program files directory contains usually a space.
3. The directory to add should be appended to **PATH** instead of replacing all directories in local copy of environment variable **PATH**.
4. On Windows XP the directory name for program files depends on OS language. Therefore better use the environment variables also on appending the directory to **PATH**.
5. Directories are added to **PATH** always without double quotes and always without trailing backslash.

It is also possible to check just environment variable **ProgramFiles(x86)** as this variable does not exist on Windows x86.

```
@echo off
if "%ProgramFiles(x86)%"=="" (
    set "PATH=%PATH%;%ProgramFiles%\McAfee\VirusScan Enterprise"
) else (
    set "PATH=%PATH%;%ProgramFiles(x86)%\McAfee\VirusScan Enterprise"
)
echo %PATH%
```

Comment: that syntax `set "ENVVAR=..."` is really mindblowing (sick) but it works

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off


if EXISTS "%ProgramFiles(x86)%" (
   set PATH_="c:\Program Files (x86)\McAfee\VirusScan Enterprise\"
) else (
  set PATH_="c:\Program Files\McAfee\VirusScan Enterprise\"
)
echo %PATH_%
REM pushd %PATH_%
```

Try with quotes around `%ProgramFiles(x86)%`